# Granting privileges to remote database via IP Address and port number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have created 2 databases :

**First** : On **local** machine having **username**: **Local_Sales2014BCS044** 
            having a relation named **remoteAccess**.

**Second** : On **remote** server having **username** : **2014BCS044** , **IP address** : **10.7.1.15** and database 
             service having the **port** : **1521**.

Now I want to grant privileges of relation named  **remoteAccsess** to **2nd** database. So I wrote a ORACLE SQL query which is not working :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Local_Sales2014BCS044.remoteAccsess TO 2014BCS044@10.7.1.15:1521;
```

Kindly suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all connect to the database on remote server using sqlplus specifying its TNS entry. Then execute the grant command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Local_Sales2014BCS044.remoteAccsess TO 2014BCS044`.

You have to make sure ports 1521 and 22 are open between the databases. This can be check by using `tnsping` command.

Comment: In SQL Developer I wrote :  **CONNECT 2014BCS044/2014BCS044@10.7.1.15:1521/pdborcl;** and the connection was successfull. But at that moment only this message was displayed: **Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected**,So connection is LOST. Kindly help!

Comment: Is the Disconnected username same as the one you are connecting with?  Try querying `select * from global_name;` or `select name from v$database;` to check whether you are connected to your local system or remote system.